# Accessing and displaying a filename of #datasource#

Tags: coldfusion

I would like to find out how to display the filename (or entire path) of a #datasource#.  The datasource connection was performed in the administrator, but I do not have access to the administrator.  Therefore I would like to find a way to display the filename of the datasource connection.

```
<cfset Results_DataSource = "mydatafile">

<cfquery name="qGetID" datasource="#Results_DataSource#">
    SELECT tournID
    FROM tblmyTable
    WHERE tblmyTable.tournID = '#uniqueid#';
</cfquery>
```

I would like to display the filename of `Results_DataSource`. Can someone please show how?

Comment: Datasources are not files, they just have a unique name that is mapped to connection details. You can access details in `cf_root\lib\neo-datasource.xml` of your ColdFusion installation.

Comment: Your code shows a datasource being used, not displayed.  All you need for that is the name of the datasource.

Comment: I recently wrote migration scripts to identify data sources, detach, copy SQL MDF files across the network, reattach and update the CF datasource host. I used the CF Admin API. I was able to get the SQL filepath by querying the MASTER table. (Search for that on StackOverflow.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A datasource is not saved as a file, but contained in the [`cf_root\lib\neo-datasource.xml` of your ColdFusion installation](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/purpose-location-xml-configuration-files.html).

You can access details about the server/database used in a datasource using the [`<cfdbinfo>` tag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7685.html).